# How to Avoid negative values result when using Countvectorizer?

Tags: python, countvectorizer

I've got a document classification problem with only 2 classes and my training dataset matrix size after the CountVectorizer/TfidfVectorizer becomes (14727, 5830)). 
I'd like to use SmartTfidfTransformer and NaiveBayes; however, CountVectorizer seems to produce negative values. I'd like to know why and how negative values can be avoided.
However when I tested this code on small data ,it works without error.
Please help me

```
Data_train=vectorizer.fit_transform(Data.FilteredArticle)
#Split Data 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Data_train ,Data.classe,test_size=0.2)


pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf', SmartTfidfTransformer()),
                       ('NaiveBayes', NB)])

param_grid = {'tfidf__weighting': ["".join(el) + 'p'
                                   for el in product('labLd', 'sd',"clu")],
              'tfidf__norm_alpha': np.linspace(0, 1, 10),
              'NaiveBayes__alpha':(1e-2, 1e-3)}
import os 
pipe_cv = GridSearchCV(pipe,
                       param_grid=param_grid,
                       verbose=1,
                       n_jobs=(1 if os.name == 'nt' else -1),
                       cv=5)
pipe_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I got this error when I executed the pipe.fit: 
ValueError: Input X must be non-negative 
The error is from the naive bayes , I cheked my data after vectorization and it does not contain any negative value

Comment: Where is the class `SmartTfidfTransformer` from? How is it different from the standard `TfidfTransformer`?

Comment: The SmartTfidfTransformer is from freediscovery.feature_weighting , it used to optimize TF-IDF schemes